# Is it possible to replace an entire node with SQL DML?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dml

I am very new to the SQL DML and I could use any help in discerning if this is possible.

```
declare @xml XML, @id int, @new XML
SET @id = 2
SET @xml = '<root><node ids=1><child /></node><node ids=2><child /></node></root>'
SET @new = '<node ids=2,3><child /></node>'
```

I would like to set the entire node element off the root to be the same as @new but I am having trouble figuring out the syntax with SQL DML.  I know the following does not work for a few reasons, but consider it almost pseudo-code towards the functionality I am trying to perform.

```
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/node[@id=sql:variable("@id")]) with sql:variable(@new)')
```

I may have more syntax wrong than I realize since I am not familiar with this stuff yet.  I know that it expects me to specify /text() for an untyped value, but I'd like to replace the wrapping "node" tag as well and that it should take the first with a [1] afterward.  What is the proper syntax for handling this sort of call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can `delete` the `node` child element and then insert new `node` element

```
SET @xml.modify(' delete (/root/node)');
SET @xml.modify('insert  sql:variable("@new") into (/root)[1]  ')
```